# How can I bind my Selected option to my model in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't seem to get my selected value to bind to my model from my drop downs.

I have a drop down like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Link to Employee</th>
    <td>
        <select id="employeeSelect" ng-controller="employeesController"
                ng-init="getEmployees(null, null)">
            <option ng-repeat="employee in data.employees"
                    value={{employee.id}} ng-selected="{{employee.id}} == @ViewBag.empId"
                    ng-model="data.employeeCase.employeeId">
                {{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

getEmployees(null, null) sets the $scope.data.employees property to:
an array of Employees with the needed properties.

My drop down items show up great.  I am able to set the default selection using ng-selected and my ViewBag value from ASP.Net MVC.

I have a Submit button like this:

SAVE

The angular controller function looks like this:

```
$scope.addCase = function (employeeCase) {

$http.post(caseUrl, employeeCase)
    .then(function (response) {
        // Test front end exception message;
        // throw "test exception";
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        $scope.data.caseInsertError = error;
    });
}
```

All of my non drop down values bind to employeeCase in the post method.

Here is one that does bind:

```
<tr>
    <th>Intitial Consult Date</th>
    <td>
        <input type="date" ng-model="data.employeeCase.initialConsultDate" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get the selecteded option (usually an id) to be passed to my angular function?

Comment: The `select` directive is used together with `ngModel` to provide data-binding between the scope and the `<select>` control (including setting default values). For more information, see [AngularJS select directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) like in this [runnable fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nuc5w7f4/2/). Your selected value gets binded to `ng-model` in your `select` element. In this example it's going to be binded on `selectedEmployeId`.

=> `ng-options="employe.id as (employe.firstName + ' ' + employe.lastName) for employe in data.employees"`

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedEmployeId" 
          ng-options="employe.id as (employe.firstName + ' ' + employe.lastName) for employe in data.employees"></select>
  <br /><br />
  SelectedId: {{ selectedEmployeId }}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    employees: [{
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'black',
      lastName: 'dark'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstName: 'white',
      lastName: 'light'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      firstName: 'red',
      lastName: 'dark'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      firstName: 'blue',
      lastName: 'dark'
    }, {
      id: 5,
      firstName: 'yellow',
      lastName: 'light'
    }]
  };

  $scope.selectedEmployeId = $scope.data.employees[0].id;
});
```

Comment: Thank you.
My default value is getting posted now.
But now I am unable to set my default selected value.
This was working:

    ng-selected="{{employee.id}} == @ViewBag.empId"

But now it now longer sets a default.

Comment: @Sam updated - please check `$scope.selectedEmployeId = $scope.data.employees[0].id;` part. `ng-selected` is not needed. It's always good to take a look at the documentation. This link is provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) in conjunciton with ng-model.

I've made a simple example to help you: https://codepen.io/miguelbaldi/pen/ZePgzx

Controller:

```
function employeesController($scope) {
    $scope.data = { 'employees': [] };
    // Selecting employee by it's ID, bound using ng-model
    $scope.selectedEmployee = { id: 2 };
    $scope.getEmployees = function(a, b) {
        $scope.data.employees = [
            { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
            { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe" }
        ];
    };
    $scope.addCase = function() {
        console.log('Employee', $scope.selectedEmployee);
        alert($scope.selectedEmployee.name);
    }

}
```

View:

```
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Angular JS Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>ng-options example</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="employeesController" ng-init="getEmployees(null, null)">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Link to Employee</th>
          <td>
            <select id="employeeSelect" ng-options="employee as employee.name for employee in data.employees track by employee.id"
              ng-model="selectedEmployee">
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="addCase()" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_submit_add_case_modal" type="button">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></i> SAVE
    </button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-model directive in select tag not in option tag.